# If the last word in 's' starts with a consonant, it will say index out of range. How do I change the program to change that?

Tags: python, indexing

```
def to_pig_latin(s):
    j = 0 # points to first character in word  
    i = 0
    new_sentence_1 = '' # variable to store strings being changed
    vowel_position = 0 # show the position of the first vowel
    number_of_words = 0
    number_of_spaces = s.count(" ") 
    number_of_words = number_of_spaces + 1

    space_position = s.find(" ") # find the position of the first space
    sent = s[:space_position] # slice the first word of the sentence
    old_sent = s[len(sent)+1:] # stores the old sentence without the first word of s

    while number_of_spaces >= 0:
        if sent[j] in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]: # checks if first character is a vowel
            new_sentence = sent + "way" # adds 'way' to the first word
            new_sentence_1 = new_sentence_1 + ' ' + new_sentence # adds the words

        else: # if first character is not equal to a vowel
            for i in range(len(sent)):
                # check to see if first character in s is a vowel
                if s[i] == 'a': 
                    break
                if s[i] == 'e':
                    break
                if s[i] == 'i':
                    break
                if s[i] == 'o':
                    break
                if s[i] == 'u':
                    break

            vowel_position = i # takes position of first vowel reached in word
            consonant_sequence = sent[:vowel_position] # stores all the consonants up to the first vowel, but not the first vowel
            sent = sent[vowel_position:] # slices the word from the first vowel to the end
            new_sentence = sent + 'a' + consonant_sequence + 'ay' # adds strings
            new_sentence_1 = new_sentence_1 + ' ' + new_sentence # adds the words

        s = old_sent # takes the value of old_sent
        space_position = s.find(" ") # find the position of the first space
```

How do I change the part below in order to for it to check even if there is one word in `s`? Or if the last word in the string `s` ends with a word that begins with one or more consonant?

```
    if space_position == -1:
        space_position = len(s)
        sent = s[:space_position]
        if sent[j] in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
            new_sentence = sent + "way"
            new_sentence_1 = new_sentence_1 + ' ' + new_sentence
            break
        else:
            for i in range(len(sent)):
                if s[i] == 'a':
                    break
                if s[i] == 'e':
                    break
                if s[i] == 'i':
                    break
                if s[i] == 'o':
                    break
                if s[i] == 'u':
                    break

        vowel_position = i
        consonant_sequence = sent[:vowel_position]
        sent = sent[vowel_position:]
        new_sentence = sent + 'a' + consonant_sequence + 'ay'
        new_sentence_1 = new_sentence_1 + ' ' + new_sentence            


    sent = s[:space_position]
    old_sent = s[len(sent)+1:]
    number_of_spaces = s.count(" ")
    number_of_words = number_of_spaces + 1

return new_sentence_1[1:]
```

test program for english/piglatin translator:

```
import piglatin

choice = input ("(E)nglish or (P)ig Latin?\n")
action = choice[:1]
if action == 'E':
    s = input("Enter an English sentence:\n")
    new_s = piglatin.to_pig_latin(s)
    print("Pig-Latin:")
    print(new_s)
elif action =='P':
    s = input("Enter a Pig Latin sentence:\n")
    new_s = piglatin.to_english(s)
    print("English:")
    print(new_s)
```

Output:

```
(E)nglish or (P)ig Latin? E
Enter an English sentence: My friend next to me is wearing a shoe
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/Resources/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py",
   line 9, in <module>
  File "/Users/azhar/Desktop/Computer Science/Assignments/Assignment 4 (Functions & Strings)/piglatin.py", line 46, in to_pig_latin
    if sent[j] in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]: # checks if first value in j is equal to a vowel
builtins.IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Your traceback is incomplete; there is text missing. Can you give us the full traceback please?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/Resources/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/Users/azhar/Desktop/Computer Science/Assignments/Assignment 4 (Functions & Strings)/piglatin.py", line 46, in to_pig_latin
    if sent[j] in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]: # checks if first value in j is equal to a vowel
builtins.IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Confused!  apple begins with the vowel not consonant.

Comment: @azhar: you can [edit] your question to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

I think, rather than fixing that specific problem, it would be easier to simplify the code.

First, you can split the sentence with `s.split()`, which will give you a list of words split on whitespace.  Second, you can use `s.find()` to find the index of a given string.  Third, you can use `' '.join(sen)` to join a list of strings using spaces.

So using these, your code reduces to this (I also added handling of capitalization):

```
def to_pig_latin(sen):
    senlst = sen.lower().split()  # split into list of words
    for i, word in enumerate(senlst):
        if word[0] in 'aeiou':
            senlst[i] += 'way'
        else:
            for vow in 'aeiou':
                ind = word.find(vow)
                if ind >= 0:
                    break
            if ind < 0: # no vowel in word
                continue
            senlst[i] = word[ind:]+'a'+word[:ind]
    newsen = ' '.join(senlst)  # combine list of words into sentence
    if sen[0].isupper():  # make capitalization like original
        newsen = newsen.capitalize()
    return newsen
```

However, if you really want to check if there is a word at all, you can do `if s.strip():`.  What this will do is strip out and leading or trailing whitespace.  If there are no words, this will leave you with an empty string.  In python, an empty string (or empty list or tuple) is considered `False`, so you can use it in an `if` test to then do whatever sort of handling of that situation you want.